# Acumatica Update does not work for Custom field

Tags: acumatica

I am facing two issues.

1. I have created the following field in SOLine
   [SOLineExt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8xsK.png)

but when I try to reference this extension from SOOrderEntry.cs it does not recognize it.

Am I missing something?

To make it work, I copied this class to the SOOrderEntry.cs and commented out in the original class.

2. The other issue that I am facing is in regard the update for this new field.
   it is updating in the cache and showing in the grid but does not update in the SOLIne DAC. Eventually I'll delete this field from the grid. I am showing it just to see if it was updating.

I am doing basically the same as the "T300_AcumaticaCustomizationPlatform_2017R2" instructed on Page 47 - 65.

a) Created an Action button

b) Defined an action delegated method

c) Added FieldUpdated Enevent Handler

Here are the copy of my codes:

[createCustomerFixedPrice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA9Gp.png)

[SOLine_UsrFixedPrice_FieldUpdated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGLoA.png)

[Sales Order Grid with UsrFixedPriced field Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRtZ6.png)

[SOLine  with UsrFixedPriced field NOT Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJKVu.png)

Any help will be gratefully appreciated, especially in the second issue.

Comment: It appears there are some formatting glitch in your question, you probably didn't mean to type I have created the following field in SOLine: "[SOLineExt][1]"

Comment: It could be helpful to post what leads you to conclude that: "but when I try to reference this extension from SOOrderEntry.cs it does not recognize it", is there any error message that says the field is not recognized?

Comment: Keep in mind that if viewing dynamic code in visual studio, intellisense does not recognize it, and that is very different than SOOrderEntry.cs does not recognize it. At runtime the code will be checked and recognized if properly setup.

Comment: If you need to have Intellisense then you will have to convert your customization to an extension library so the DAC are included as static reference: https://help.acumatica.com/(W(63))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=f7e12f94-c8be-4013-8990-9341161bb252

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your new field using Acumatica Project Editor?

Like this:
[image]

When you create a database bound field (type PXDBType instead of PXType) using the project editor it automatically adds the matching DB script to create the database column:
[image]

From your question it's not clear if you created the DAC directly in a source code file or using Acumatica Project Editor. So I would recommend you check if the database script was created and if not create it manually. Then Save the customization project, re-publish it and if possible check with a database utility if the field actually exists in database.

Also you used default namespace and extension name for your extension DAC:

```
PX.Objects.SO.SOLineExt
```

Since that is the default it could clash with other customizations that also use the same defaults. To reduce chance of a conflict you could change the default namespace to your own:

```
MyNamespace.SOLineExt
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your collaboration.
 
Yes, I created the field using Acumatica Project Editor.
The field exist in the DB . The "SOLine with UsrFixedPriced field NOT Updated" link in the post, shows the picture of the field existence in the SOLIne table.

Comment: Please set the UsrFixedPriced control editor Type property to "CheckBox" and Enabled to "True" then remove *all* the code that is setting the UsrFixedPriced value. After that try to change value in UI, save in UI and refresh the page, see if the change sticks.

Comment: Also from the screenshots I can't see the DB type, it needs to be of 'bit' type to save properly.

Comment: Changing the control type to checkbox did the trick.
Once again Thank you very much for your Help.